# two Listboxes, One selection in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listbox

I am using asp.net (C#) and I need your help with this thing.

I have two listboxes, one is bound to get a list of companies  from the DB (lstCompanies) and the other one is for the user to filter that companies (lstFilter).

The problem occurs when the user selects from both listboxes and submit! so I need to do the following in JAVASCRIPT:

When the user selects from lstCompanies, check if lstFilter is selected; I need to clear the selection for him. And vice versa!

It has to be JS to avoid postbacks, and I am forced to run this webapp in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in the change event of lstCompanies

```
document.getElementById("lstFilter").selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through a loop and deselect all

```
for(i=0; i<document.form1.lstFilter.options.length; i++)
{
    document.form1.lstFilter.options[i].selected = false;
}
```